# Generate a file next to the jar file containing the code

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a jar with my application that should create a file next to it. So in folder I will have this :

`Source 
 |_ MyApplication.jar
 |_ generatedFile.txt`

Easy thing I thought... nope.. I am lost... I have a code like this:

```
URL location = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        String path = location.getFile().substring(0, location.getFile().lastIndexOf("/MyContext"));
        File file = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        File file1 = new File(path + "/MyFileName.txt");
        File file2 = new File(path.substring(1) + "/MyFileName.txt");
```

I tried different combinations, googled alot and I am lost... if I get for example

```
file1.getPath();
file2.getAbsolutePath();
```

and so on, the paths are correct... but the file isn't generated... Only working case is the first one, but that is located inside the jar and I don't want that.

I also tried to moving the existing file outside using

```
Paths.move(...
```

but that hasn't helped me at all..

Can someone help me with this ? And explain to me why isn't the examples above working ? Thanks..

Comment: did you call `file1.createNewFile()` after creating a File instance?

Comment: Thanks.. this solved the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `File file = new File("my path string");` just creates a Java `File` Object instance in memory.  You need to write something to the actual file you are targeting.  The simplest way to create an empty file is to call `file.createNewFile()`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, that helped me